# Cannot save record in VF and Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

My VF page shows output from one custom object, but I want to save input into a different object using a form and inputfields.
All I am getting back is NULL, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I thought VF and Apex shared the variable automagically, but maybe I missed something.

## APEX CODE

```
public class testRunController {
    
    public Case_Test_Results__c testResults {get; set;}
    
    Public Integer size {get;set;}
    Public Integer noOfRecords {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> paginationSizeOptions {get;set;}
    
    public testRunController() {
        size=1;
        paginationSizeOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('2', '2'));
    }
    
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get {
            if(setCon == null) {
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
                Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Expected_Results__c, Instructions__c, TestScenario__c 
                                          FROM Case_Test_Suite__c 
                                          WHERE recordType__c='SLA_SLO' ORDER BY TestScenario__c ASC]));
                
                setCon.setPageSize(size);
                noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
            }
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public PageReference refreshPageSize() {
        setCon.setPageSize(size);
        return null;
    }
    
    public List<Case_Test_Suite__c> getTSRecords() {
        return (List<Case_Test_Suite__c>) setCon.getRecords();
    }
    
    public PageReference callTwoMethods() {
        System.debug('#### testResults=' + testResults);
        if(setCon.getPageNumber() == noOfRecords){
            save();
            return Page.endTestRun;
        }
        
        setCon.next();
        Save();
        return null;
    }
    
    public PageReference Save(){
        System.debug('#### testResults=' + testResults);
        //insert testResults;
        return null;
    }//end saveResults
    
    }//
```

## VF CODE:

```
<apex:page controller="testRunController">
    <style type="text/css">
        .inputBox {width: 300px;}
    </style>
    
        <!--<apex:actionFunction name="refreshPageSize" action="{!refreshPageSize}" status="fetchStatus" reRender="pbId"/> -->
        <apex:pageBlock id="pbId">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Test Run" collapsible="false" columns="1">
                <apex:dataTable value="{!TSRecords}" var="ts">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Test Scenario Number</apex:facet>
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ts.TestScenario__c}"></apex:outputText>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:dataTable>
                
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!TSRecords}" var="ts">
                     
                    <apex:column headerValue="Instructions">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!ts.Instructions__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Expected Results">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!ts.Expected_Results__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock>
        <!-- Test Results Section -->
        <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Test Results"/>
            <div align="center">
                <apex:dataTable value="{!TSRecords}" var="ts">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Test Scenario Number</apex:facet>
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ts.TestScenario__c}"></apex:outputText>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:dataTable>
            </div> 
            <p />
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField styleClass="inputBox" value="{!testResults.Notes_and_Observations__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField styleClass="inputBox" value="{!testResults.Actual_Results__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!testResults.Created_Case_URL__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!testResults.Pass_or_Fail__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
            <apex:pageBlockSection >

                
                <div align="center">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!callTwoMethods}" value="Save Test Result"/>    
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized your variable, so it's null. You just need to add a line of code to your constructor:

```
public testRunController() {
  testResults = new Case_Test_Results__c();
```

You may also need to reset it each time you call save successfully:

```
public void save() {
  insert testResults;
  testResults = new Case_Test_Results__c();
}
```

As a side note, if you don't plan on returning a value, always use the "void" return type. This eliminates the need for "return null" and makes your code's intent clear.